# Capturing KeyEvent On Android Virtual keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-keypad

Is there any way to capture the keyevents on android virtual keyboard, during typing into an EditText?

I want to capture the deleteKey event?

Comment: Regular key listeners are probably handles KeyEvents from virtual keyboard. Have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice sample piece of code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL) { 
/*Just switch out keycode if KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL if its not the correct one*/
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CLICKED Delete KEY",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Didnt work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
    };
```

I put in toasts just so you can test if the key is pressed or not.
Also the developers website [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) has a lot of really good information.

Answer (score 0):

This code is works very well. Give it a shot, please.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnKeyListener {
......
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("setOnKeyListener", "Key Code:" + String.valueOf(keyCode));
        if(event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;
        Log.e("setOnKeyListener-ACTION_DOWN", "Key Code:" + String.valueOf(keyCode));
        return false;
    }
}
```